# complex if statement runs code regardless of condition output

Tags: javascript, validation

**JS**

```js
if (isNaN(BDyear) == true || isNaN(BDmonth) == true || 
    isNaN(BDday) == true || BDday.length != 2 || 
    BDmonth.length != 2 || BDyear.length != 4)
{
    document.getElementById("BDyear").value = ''
    document.getElementById("BDmonth").value = ''
    document.getElementById("BDday").value = ''
    document.getElementById("bderror").style.display = "inline"
    BDstate = false BDcheck = false
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>שנת לידה</td>
    <td>
        <input class="text" id="BDyear" maxlength="4" style="width:8%" />&nbsp/&nbsp
        <input class="text" id="BDmonth" maxlength="2" style="width:5%" />&nbsp/&nbsp
        <input class="text" id="BDday" maxlength="2" style="width:5%" />
        <br />
        <p id="bderror" style="position:absolute; top:70%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none">תאריך לידה לא תקין</p>
        <p id="bderroryoung" style="position:absolute; top:70%; color:red; font:65% arial; display:none">חובה להיות מעל גיל 13</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

the script part runs regardless whether i put in the inputs a number or words, with any length and i don't understand why is it running, but i'm suspecting it's the "isNaN" function that is not working correctly from different tries and setups. it's supposed to find out if the content entered is only a numric value that is in the proper length for dd/mm/yyyy and if it's all false it's supposed to leave everything as is and BDcheck var to be true so the next if statement will run

Any suggestions?

Comment: is the script in a function?  I don't see where this would be called other than inline as the document loads, but even then it isn't in a script tag.  Please clean up your samples so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: Tip: Don't compare true boolean values to `true` or `false`. When a value is actually a boolean, rather than merely "truthy" or "falsey", just use `if (isNaN(BDyear) || isNaN(BDmonth) || etc.)`. There is a slight difference if you use triple-equals `if (getSomeBoolean(x) === true)` but again, only if you are getting truthy/falsey values instead of booleans. Also read about [how isNan() is "broken"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: How can i say then : if isNaN comes out true/false do something without actually using the true and false values?

Comment: I found out what was my issue. It's pretty ridiculous. I said if the length of day and month is not equal to 2 without taking into consideration that those vales could be a single character values when i testing a date that does have 1 number in the month. Which came out true at all times

Answer (score 0):

Make sure BDyear, BDday and BDmonth actually contain values; you may need to use `document.getElementById("BDyear").value` inside the isNaN functions.  The value is also probably a string, so you may want to try first casting it to a number before checking isNaN like this: `isNaN(Number(document.getElementById("BDyear").value))`.

Also, isNaN returns a Boolean, so comparing it to true is redundant.  You can just write it like `if (isNaN(BDyear) || isNaN(BDmonth) || isNaN(BDday) || BDday.length != 2 || BDmonth.length != 2 || BDyear.length != 4)`, possibly with the changes I just suggested.

Ultimately, the code could look like this:

```
//assuming BDstate and BDcheck variables are already defined
var year = document.getElementById("BDyear");
var month = document.getElementById("BDmonth");
var day = document.getElementById("BDday");
if (isNaN(Number(year.value)) || isNaN(Number(month.value) || isNaN(Number(day.value)) || day.value.length != 2 || month.value.length != 2 || year.value.length != 4)
{
    year.value = ''
    month.value = ''
    day.value = ''
    document.getElementById("bderror").style.display = "inline"
    BDstate = false
    BDcheck = false
}
```

Also, instead of checking that the string length of month is 2 characters, you may want to check whether the numeric value is between a valid range.  For example, a user would currently have to enter `"06"` (without an leading or trailing spaces, btw) in order for the check to succeed, whereas they could enter `"   6   "` if you were actually checking that the numeric value is within a valid range like `(Number(month.value) >= 1 && Number(month.value) <= 12)`.  The same goes for the day and year.

Comment: I'll try to read over what you said enough times till i understand it :] (p.s i'm a COMPLETE rookie. first year of programming). but the notes have been taken into consideration and will try your solution. Thank you.